# Getting the last record inserted into a select query

Tags: mysql

I am creating a small message board and I am stuck

I can select the subject, the original author, the number of replies but what I can't do is get the username, topic or date of the last post.

There are 3 tables, boards, topics and messages.

I want to get the author, date and topic of the last message in the message table.  The author and date field are already fields on the messages table but i would need to join the messages and topics table on the topicid field.

this is my query that selects the subject, author, and number of replies

```
SELECT t.topicname, t.author, count( message ) AS message
  FROM topics t
  INNER JOIN messages m
    ON m.topicid = t.topicid
  INNER JOIN boards b
    ON b.boardid = t.boardid
  WHERE b.boardid = 1
  GROUP BY t.topicname
```

Can anyone please help me get this finished?

This is what my tables look like

```
CREATE TABLE `boards` (
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `boardname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`boardid`)
);


CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `messageid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `date` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`messageid`)
);

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `topicname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`topicid`)
);
```

Comment: What else is needed?  Getting the last message?

Comment: This is my first time here so i don't know if i'm doing this right

Basically, i need that query but an extra field/s which is the username, date/time, and topic so i thought of a nested query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your SQL supports the LIMIT clause,

```
SELECT m.author, m.date, t.topicname FROM messages m 
JOIN topics t ON m.topicid = t.topicid 
ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1
```

otherwise:

```
SELECT m.author, m.date, t.topicname FROM messages m 
JOIN topics t ON m.topicid = t.topicid 
WHERE m.date = (SELECT max(m2.date) from messages m2)
```

EDIT: if you want to combine this with the original query, it has to be rewritten using subqueries to extract the message count and the date of last message:

```
SELECT t.topicname, t.author, 
      (select count(message) from messages m where m.topicid = t.topicid) AS messagecount, 
       lm.author, lm.date
  FROM topics t
  INNER JOIN messages lm
    ON lm.topicid = t.topicid AND lm.date = (SELECT max(m2.date) from messages m2)
  INNER JOIN boards b
    ON b.boardid = t.boardid
  WHERE b.boardid = 1
  GROUP BY t.topicname
```

also notice that if you don't pick any field from table boards, you don't need the last join:

```
SELECT t.topicname, t.author, 
      (select count(message) from messages m where m.topicid = t.topicid) AS messagecount, 
       lm.author, lm.date
  FROM topics t
  INNER JOIN messages lm
    ON lm.topicid = t.topicid AND lm.date = (SELECT max(m2.date) from messages m2)
  WHERE t.boardid = 1
  GROUP BY t.topicname
```

EDIT: if mysql doesn't support subqueries in the field list, you can try this:

```
SELECT t.topicname, t.author, mc.messagecount, lm.author, lm.date
  FROM topics t
  JOIN (select m.topicid, count(*) as messagecount from messages m group by m.topicid) as mc 
    ON mc.topicid = t.topicid
  JOIN messages lm
    ON lm.topicid = t.topicid AND lm.date = (SELECT max(m2.date) from messages m2)
  WHERE t.boardid = 1
  GROUP BY t.topicname
```

Comment: That works for getting the last post of the messages table but how do i combine that wioth my original query?

Comment: That looks like exactly what i'm trying to do but i get this error message

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count( message ) from messages m where m . topicid = t .

Comment: Sorry, this is standard SQL but I don't know much about mysql. Maybe it doesn't support subqueries in the field list. Or maybe it has a different syntax for them.

Comment: If you do something like "WHERE field=(SELECT etc" is that a subquery becuase if it is, my mysql version does support it

I don't know why it's not accepting everything you suggest

Comment: every (SELECT ... ) inside another SELECT is a subquery. Most database allow subqueries in the FROM or the WHERE part of the main query, but not all of them allow subqueries in the field list of the SELECT. Have you tried the last version I posted?

Comment: This worked on a different version of MySQL.

Thanks for all your help and it does exactly what i wanted.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subselect. Eg.:

```
select * from messages where id = (select max(id) from messages)
```

edit: And if you identify the newest record by a timestamp, you'd use:

```
select * from messages where id = (
  select id
  from messages
  order by post_time desc
  limit 1)
```

Comment: This assumes that the id field makes sense to find the largest. What if it's a GUID?

Comment: Well, I just made a wild guess, since I don't know the table structure. The query would look slightly different, but it'll still be a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the latest entry in a table, you should have a `DateTime` field that shows when the entry was created (or updated). You can then sort on this column and select the latest one.

But if your `id` field is a number, you could find the highest. But I would recommend against this because it makes many assumptions and you would be fixed to numerical ids in the future.

Comment: I have a timestamp field in the messages table

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL this should work:

```
SELECT author, date, topicname as topic FROM messages LEFT JOIN topics ON messages.topicid = topics.topicid ORDER BY date DESC, LIMIT 0, 1;
```